# Trigger After Update Returns Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the following trigger to update two columns in my table when any record is inserted or updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test 
ON mytable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t
    SET UPDATE_TIMESTAMP = GETDATE(),
        UPDATE_USER_NAME = SUSER_SNAME()
    FROM mytable t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t._ID = i._ID
END
GO
```

However, it does not update the columns `UPDATE_TIMESTAMP` and `UPDATE_USER_NAME`  and still returns the default null. Could you please help me how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: A trigger doesn't *return* anything, really ....

Comment: Have you tried rewriting this as an After Insert trigger? If so, what happened?

Comment: You wrote an update trigger - so nothing will happen when you perform an insert.

Comment: Thanks @SMor, I need to take both update and insert into account. Do you have any hint for me? I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, actually, i meant the cols be filled once any update or insert is done, after creating that trigger. Is there any way I can fix it you think? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are  facing a recursing call in your trigger

Try with this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER test 
ON mytable
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN;

    UPDATE t
    SET UPDATE_TIMESTAMP = GETDATE(),
        UPDATE_USER_NAME = SUSER_SNAME()
    FROM mytable t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t._ID = i._ID
END
GO
```